# JQuery get value from loop using an array key/value

Tags: jquery

I am looping data in JQuery, and I want to retrieve a specific key from an array

So I tried this code inside the loop to get the key from a value returned in the loop

```
data[i].dns_types[ data[i].type ]
```

But that doesn't work, I created a fiddle below to recreate my code.

Getting the value of `dns_types[ data[i].type ]` returns the correct value from the array

https://jsfiddle.net/h7cgbyqt/

Comment: Your `data` does not have `dns_types`. It's two separate variables

Comment: @Justinas, I know, `dns_types` is an array. So I want to get the value from the `data` loop using a value from the array. For example if `data[i].type` is "target", then I want to read `data[i].target`

Comment: Aside from what Justinas commented, `dns_types` is a string as per your fiddle. Make it an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `dns_types` is string, so you need to parse it as JSON
2. You must use `data` and `dns_types` as two separate variables

```js
var dns_types = '{"A":"ip","AAAA":"ipv6","CNAME":"target","MX":"","TXT":"","SRV":"","NS":""}';
var dnsTypesJson = JSON.parse(dns_types);

var data = [
    {
        "target": "1.2.3.5",
        "ref": 56283838,
        "host": "www.computerbuilder.co.uk",
        "type": "CNAME"
    },
    {
        "target": "129.0.0.1",
        "ref": 56283838,
        "host": "www.computerbuilder.co.uk",
        "type": "CNAME"
    }
];

for(var i in data) {
    let subData = data[i];
    let type = dnsTypesJson[subData.type];
  
    alert(subData[type]);
}
```